# Fill two Excel charts using a two arrays

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have asked this question before and I am grateful for the help I received but the problem persists. I am trying to plot a Shear-Force and Bending-Moment diagram calculated from the loads. I create two arrays of points which I pass over to two named charts.

The program is stalling at the `.SeriesCollection(1).Values = SFnode` and the `BMnode`.

My code

```
Sub DOGRAPH()

'Calculate the Maximum BM by calculating the area of the SF diagram
    
'Data
    Dim L As Single, UDL As Single, RA As Single

        L = 3 'm
        UDL = 1 'kN/m
        RA = L * UDL / 2
        
'Global variable
    Dim i As Integer
        
'Declare the nodes
    Dim nNodes As Integer
    Dim SFnode() As Variant, BMnode() As Variant 'Graph points
        
    'Number of nodes
        nNodes = L * 1000 'Divide length into mm
        
    ReDim SFnode(nNodes), BMnode(nNodes)
    
'Do the SF and BM Diagrams
    Dim SFsum As Single 'Sum the area of the SF diagram
       
        SFnode(0) = RA       'First Node = RA
        SFsum = 0
        
        For i = 1 To nNodes
            SFnode(i) = RA - UDL * i / 1000 'SF Diagram
            SFsum = SFsum + SFnode(i)
            BMnode(i) = SFsum               'BM Diagram
        Next i
       
    Dim cSF As Chart, cBM As Chart
    
    'The charts have been named in the sheet

    Set cSF = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("SFdiagram").Chart
    Set cBM = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("BMdiagram").Chart
        
    With cSF
    
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = SFnode
   
    End With
       
    With cBM
    
       .SeriesCollection(1).Values = BMnode
        
    End With

    Set cSF = Nothing
    Set cBM = Nothing

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Lots of examples on SO about how to do this.

Comment: What kind of charts do you have? I tested your code, on an example I have, only making a function to calculate the arrays and it works as expected. If you want, I can post my (working) code.

Comment: I have studied this and followed the examples.  I have managed to get it to work using this code but now its stopped. I am stumped.  I am hoping someone will get it to work on their PC.  All you need is two charts renamed as mine.

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: My charts are Line type, not scatter.

Comment: It should work on Line type, but it looks more spectacular on Clustered Column. I will post the code.

Comment: Why was I marked down two points for my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next way. It processes two Cluster Column charts type.
**Edited:***

Your pseudo chart form the downloaded workbook cannot be used in this way. Without any series, it should be obvious that `cBM.SeriesCollection(1)` will return an error in any circumstances. Please, **delete your existing charts** and run the next code. It, firstly, will create two chats and their first 'Series' and then it will only change/refresh their `Series1` series:

```
Sub ChartFromArray() 'creation firstly
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arr, cSF As Chart, cBM As Chart

 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 
 arr = makeArrays
 'for SFdiagram chart:_____________________________________________
 On Error Resume Next
  Set cSF = sh.ChartObjects("SFdiagram").Chart
  If Err.Number = -2147024809 Then
      Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
      Set cSF = sh.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=1, Top:=10, _
                                    Width:=300, Height:=300).Chart
      cSF.ChartType = xlColumnStacked: cSF.Parent.Name = "SFdiagram"
      cSF.SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = arr(0)
  Else
      On Error GoTo 0
      cSF.SeriesCollection(1).Values = arr(0)
  End If:
  '________________________________________________________________
  
  'for BMdiagram chart:_____________________________________________
  On Error Resume Next
   Set cBM = sh.ChartObjects("BMdiagram").Chart
   If Err.Number = -2147024809 Then
      Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
      Set cBM = sh.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=cSF.Parent.Width + 5, _
                            Top:=10, Width:=300, Height:=300).Chart
      cBM.ChartType = xlColumnStacked: cBM.Parent.Name = "BMdiagram"
      cBM.SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = arr(1)
   Else
       On Error GoTo 0
       cBM.SeriesCollection(1).Values = arr(1)
   End If
   '________________________________________________________________
End Sub
```

It uses the next function to calculate the two necessary arrays, so copy it, too:

```
Function makeArrays() As Variant
 Dim L As Single, UDL As Single, RA As Single, i As Integer

    L = 3: UDL = 1: RA = L * UDL / 2 'kN/m
        
    'Declare the nodes
    Dim nNodes As Integer
    Dim SFnode() As Variant, BMnode() As Variant 'Graph points
        
    'Number of nodes
        nNodes = L * 1000 'Divide length into mm
        
    ReDim SFnode(nNodes), BMnode(nNodes)
    
    'Do the SF and BM Diagrams
    Dim SFsum As Single 'Sum the area of the SF diagram
       
    SFnode(0) = RA       'First Node = RA
    SFsum = 0
        
    For i = 1 To nNodes
        SFnode(i) = RA - UDL * i / 1000 'SF Diagram
        SFsum = SFsum + SFnode(i)
        BMnode(i) = SFsum               'BM Diagram
    Next i
  makeArrays = Array(SFnode, BMnode)
End Function
```

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: @user3140681: You were enthusiastic some hours before. Couldn't you test the above code? If tested, a little feedback should not kill anybody...

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Had to do a site visit.  Thanks for the code but I still get the same error. Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.  Is it possible that it is something to do with the Charts or Excel.

Comment: @user3140681: If nothing confidential, can you share the workbook? You can use a transfer site. [Here](https://easyupload.io/) is a free one, easy to be used...

Comment: FaneDuru. I put the Book on my server.  This is the link: www.hemis.co.uk/Book1.xlsm.

Comment: Would the problem lie in the Tools/References section.  I am using Excel 2007 but the PC did have later copies of Excel installed that have been removed.

Comment: @user3140681: OK. I will download it and give you a sign rapidly.

Comment: @user3140681:  Your so named 'charts' cannot be filled as they are. Without any series, it is not possible to use `.SeriesCollection(1)`, since a series collection does not exist. I must leave home now and I will post a piece of code able to create two such charts, a series for each and fill them with data you need. If you want to transform the code in one only firstly creating them and then only fill the (now existing series(1)) with data...

Comment: @user3140681: Posted the code as explained above. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: @user3140681: I am back home and created a  `Sub` able to firstly create the charts and then to only refresh their `Series1` series with the new data. Please, download from [here](https://easyupload.io/7fbbi9) the updated workbook and send some feedback. It will stay there for only 7 days. You will find a button on its single existing sheet. Pressing it, the charts will be created and a series for each, too. Then, their `Series1` will be refreshed with the new data. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: FaneDuru.  Thank you very much.  The code worked perfectly.

Comment: @hemis: Glad I could help!